# Function Structure Diagram for Tennis ball launcher

Tags: diagram, project-management

I created this Function structure diagram for a tennis ball launcher for my homework and am not sure about inputs and outputs please- are they correct please- it feels like I could include more in the diagram to better explain the function- just not sure what to do next please?

My tennis ball launcher allows you to control the RPM and inclination only.

[image]

lighter arrow: forms of energy, bold arrow: materials and dotted arrow: signals. This is what I used to form this? Can someone recommend reading material on Function structure diagrams too please?

Comment: Why do you not think that it is or is not correct?  This site is meant to help you understand engineering, not to check your work. If there is something about these diagrams that you are having trouble with, ask about that idea specifically.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. Sorry haven’t used this site before, I should of explained my question better.

Comment: I’ll help, as no one else likes these small questions— Might be right, FSD are usually inputs then outputs as you got